# Regex: Get after last occurence

Tags: regex, grep

When my string looks like this:

```
Something (foo@bar.com@baz.com) something...
```

How can I get `foo@bar.com` and `baz.com` using regex/grep?

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\()[^)]*(?=@)|(?<=@)[^)]*(?=\))'
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "Something (foo@bar.com@baz.com) something..."|grep -Po '(?<=\()[^)]*(?=@)|(?<=@)[^)]*(?=\))'
foo@bar.com
baz.com
```